# Navigation Container not showing without <ScrollView>

Tags: react-native

I'm a React Native student. I'm sorry if this is a basic issue.

I have only one component in my project that is called Main - this component is imported in App.js. (Important: I removed all styles in App.js already)

So - here's my code in Main.JS.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Search from '../Search'
import ClientsRegister from '../ClientRegister'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    
      
      <ScrollView>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator 
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                let iconName;

                if (route.name === 'Home') {
                  iconName = focused ? 'ios-information-circle' : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
                } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
                  iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
                }

                // You can return any component that you like here!
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
              },
            })}
            tabBarOptions={{
              activeTintColor: 'tomato',
              inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            }}
          >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        </ScrollView> 
    
  );
}
```

See the `<ScrollView>`? Of course - that's not the right thing to do. But If I use `<View>` only - the navigation bar disappears.

So - here are both cases for you. I Think it will be really gigantic here... but here are the prints.

**With `<ScrollView>`**
[image: With]

**With `<View>`**

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I Need to use the VIEW, of course, but it's not appearing. Oh, for the case it was hiding at the bottom, behind the control buttons, I tried to put `<View style={{marginBottom:100}}>` but didn't work either.

(I really need to charge my phone, don't I?)

Comment: NavigationContainer is generally used as the root, why do you need a scroll view around that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello similar to what @Meyer Buaharon said - to fix this you need to change:

```
<View>
   <NavigationContainer>
     ...
   </NavigationContainer>
</View>
```

To:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}> 
   <NavigationContainer>
     ...
   </NavigationContainer>
</View>
```

This means the View fills the entire screen.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but it's still not working with ``<View style={{flex:1}}>``

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that the scroll view show the content and the view doesn't

```
<View style={{flex:'1'}}>

...

</View>
```

Hope this solves it

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but it's still not working with ``<View style={{flex:1}}>``

Answer (score 0):

Maaaan....

Idk why but I moved the code directly to App.js instead doing it in Main.js and importing.

Now it's working.
I really hate life sometimes. (Just kidding...don't really hate life)